# How to create a 3D array where the k'th element is a 2x2 matrix for which I defined the coefficients in vectors

Tags: python, arrays

First of all : I am beginner in python (I use to code in matlab). So I will probably be confused between list and arrays when I explain.

I need to create a 3d array such that the first element is a 2x2 matrix, the second as well etc.

For this purpose, I had in mind to create the 4 vectors that define all my inputs datas : v1,v2,v3,v4 of length $n$

I want the k'th matrix of the 3D array I will create to have the elements : [[v1[k], v2[k]],[v3[k],v4[k]]]

For example take the following vectors :

```
v1=np.array([1, 2, 3])
v2=10*v1
v3=10*v2
v4=10*v3
```

How can I make a 3D array "A" such that A[1]=[[2, 20],[200,2000]] with my example ?

Answer (score 0):

Allright actually I think I found something working :

```
v1=np.array([1, 2, 3])
v2=10*v1
v3=10*v2
v4=10*v3

A=np.transpose(np.vstack((v1,v2,v3,v4))).reshape(-1,2,2)
```